# Can't render index.php using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

Nginx directory structure

```
nginx
├──  conf
├──  contrib
├──  docs
├──  html
├──  logs
├──  temp
│    nginx.exe
```

In the conf directory I edited the *nginx.conf* file like so:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

In the html directory I have an *index.html* and an *index.php* page.
What works is running the localhost/index.html. My problem is when trying to access the localhost/index.php I get status code *502 Bad Gateway*.

How can I troubleshoot it further?

I looked at these posts and didn't find an obvious answer:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305230/nginx-not-executing-php)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978154/why-is-my-php-not-being-rendered-why-is-my-php-page-blank).

Comment: Check the error log for additional information.

Comment: After checking the logs I got this. *No connection could be made because the machine actively refused it while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"*

Comment: So the problem is not Nginx. The problem is that the service running on `127.0.0.1:9000` is not running.